# Is there a WooCommerce shortcode to display the shop (products)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am making a restaurant site with delivery and take out. Delivery will have WooCommerce add to cart buttons and checkout. Takeout will not have the add to cart buttons. Is there a shortcode for the shop page that I can drop in a WP page and create a new class to remove the add to cart buttons? Is there a way to accomplish this in a different way?

Thank you,
-Chad

Answer (score 2):

> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9

The `[products]` shortcode is one of our most robust shortcodes, which can replace various other strings used in earlier versions of WooCommerce.

The `[products]` shortcode allows you to display products by post ID, SKU, categories, attributes, with support for pagination, random sorting, and product tags, replacing the need for multiples shortcodes such as  `[featured_products]`, `[sale_products]`, `[best_selling_products]`, `[recent_products]`, `[product_attribute]`, and `[top_rated_products]`.

Answer (score -3):

Shop shortcode is [woocommerce_products]

Comment: consider adding a reference link